# python3 как с помощью subprocess вывести текст в программе

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, subprocess

например я могу отдать команду в cmd:

```
os.system("tasklist")
```

можно ли с помощью subrocess вывести список в программе?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13525882/4711135

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно как-то так:

```py
import subprocess
args = ["tasklist"]
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = process.communicate()

for line in data:
    if line:
        line = line.strip()
        print(line.decode("cp866"))
```